# Where do I use the Control Room Key in Mor Ardain's Old Factory?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I found a Control Room Key by Bulge Harbor in the Old Factory of Mor Ardain. I vaguely remember a locked door in the factory, but I can't remember where it was. I can find information about [the key's location](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/204208-xenoblade-chronicles-2/76191483), but not the Control Room itself.

Where do I use the Control Room Key in Mor Ardain's Old Factory?

[image: key item obtained: control room key]

[image: key to the control room of the old factory in Mor Ardain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Old Factory's Control Room is near where you were held prisoner. Fast travel to the Ether Refinery Corridor then the door will be behind you down the hallway.

[image: map with ether refinery]

[image: the locked control room door]